# modX If Statement return nothing

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I want to write only output if needed, but it returns nothing.  No a and no b.

```
[[+mobilephone]] <- not empty
[[!If? &subject=`[[+mobilephone]]` &operator=`notempty` &then=`a` &else=`b`]]
```

maybe you have an idea. My Context is a Site which called a Snippet which call a Chunk.

Version Info:

MODX Revolution 2.2.10-pl (sdk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with normal output modifiers:

```
[[+mobilephone:notempty=`a`:else=`b`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the **&** from **subject** i.e. try

```
[[!If? &subject=`[[+mobilephone]]` &operator=`notempty` &then=`a` &else=`b`]]
```

Comment: oh c/p fail that was corrected in my code. unfortunately it was not the mistake